# Creating a REST API key for HERE maps - "Something went wrong, please try again"

Tags: here-api

I am trying to generate a REST api ID, api Key pair. I have generated the api id, but when I go to generate the api key I get the error "Something went wrong, please try again". I waited a few minutes and then tried again- no change.

Any advice?

Comment: We tried to test this on the portal and it is working fine ,Could you please try to logout from the portal and retry.

Comment: thanks - just tried that. No difference. Could you possibly delete the App ID "53UQj9kN4dvNhA09P3RW" and I'll start the process from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to test this on the portal and it is working fine ,Could you please try to logout from the portal and retry